# Nginx redirect https to https

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a https domain like https://example.com to https://example.com/something with nginx. it works properly when I use http://example.com in my browser but not working with https://example.com. my configuration is like below.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name/something;
}
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name/something;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't configured any SSL certificates for your SSL server block.

Comment: Where is `https://example.com/something` handled? At the moment you are creating a redirection loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing TLS certificates so even if you configure the redirect the browser will only respond with certificate error.
   You must configure the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives

And you must specify **ssl** and **http2** on the listening directive for HTTP/2

For HTTP/3 **http3** implies mandatory ssl, so no **ssl** directive should be specified in that case.

2. Your configuration has an infinite redirection loop which makes the server unusable.
   Especially you are infinitely redirecting to HTTPS.
3. Your server is lacking IPv6 support.

You should do something like this:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
      return 308 https://$host$request_uri/something;
    }
}
server {
    listen              0.0.0.0:443 http3 reuseport;
    listen              0.0.0.0:443 http2 ssl;
    listen              [::]:443 http3 reuseport;
    listen              [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    server_name         $YOURDOMAIN;
    ssl_certificate    $CERT_PATH;
    ssl_certificate_key $CERT_KEY;
[...]
}
```

See also the Mozilla TLS configuration tool to help you:
https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/

And adjust it to your needs.

*Note: The above config lines regarding to http3 only is useful if you compile NGINX with HTTP/3 support, which is only available on nginx-quic branch.*